# Yii - One to many update form

Tags: php, loops, yii, one-to-many, models

I have a one to many relationship where a movie can have many youtubeclips.. Ive managed to create the models and display the movie data inside the update form. I now need to be able to create a loop of some sort to out put my many relationship data into the form.. But cant seem to figure out how to do it.. This is what I have so far..

MovieController --

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{


    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $modelYoutubeVideo=$this->loadYoutubeVideoModel($id);
    $modelTwitterFeed=$this->loadTwitterModel($id);

    if(isset($_POST['Movie']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Movie'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'modelYoutubeVideo'=>$modelYoutubeVideo,
        'modelTwitterFeed'=> $modelTwitterFeed
    ));
}
```

Update Form --

```
<div class="row clone">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelYoutubeVideo,'embed_code'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($modelYoutubeVideo,'embed_code[]',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($modelYoutubeVideo,'embed_code'); ?>

    <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelYoutubeVideo,'description'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($modelYoutubeVideo,'description[]',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>250)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($modelYoutubeVideo,'description'); ?>
</div>
<?php
    $this->widget('ext.widgets.reCopy.ReCopyWidget', array(
        'targetClass'=>'clone',
    ));
?>
```

Need to Create a loop which outputs my data from the many relations ship table --

```
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($modelYoutubeVideo); ++$i) {

        ($modelYoutubeVideo->embed_code[i]);
        ($modelYoutubeVideo->embed_code[i]);

    }
?>
```

Movie Relationships --

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'competitions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Competition', 'movie_id'),
        'studio' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Studio', 'studio_id'),
        'country' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Country', 'country_id'),
        'movieRating' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MovieRating', 'movie_rating_id'),
        'mapPin' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MapPin', 'map_pin_id'),
        'twitterFeeds' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TwitterFeed', 'movie_id'),
        'YoutubeVideo' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'YoutubeVideo', 'movie_id'),
    );
}
```

Comment: how do want to display the data? want to display in detailView?

Comment: CActiveForm it set as

Comment: ok please post the relations in your movie model

Comment: thanks ive updated my question hope you can help cant seem to work out how to get the many relationship into my form so it can be edited! thanks

Comment: This is the 5th question you have asked, you had proper answers to all of them yet you never accepted any answer.

Comment: I cant accept answers yet sorry requires a 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

in your actionUpdate you can use use relation like this

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
$youTubevideos=$model->YoutubeVideo;
```

Here YouTubeVideo is the same relation name in your model.It will bring you all the youtubeVideo active records related to specific movie. Now pass this array to your view like

```
 $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'modelYoutubeVideo'=>$modelYoutubeVideo,
        'modelTwitterFeed'=> $modelTwitterFeed,
         'youTubeVideos'=>$youTubeVideos,
    ));
```

then in your view use foreach loop to show each value of the model like

```
foreach($youTubeVideos as $video)
{
echo $video->name;
}
```

In above echo statement actually you can echo any thing like CdetailView widget or anything you want repeatedly.

Comment: Brillant that sounds great!! gonna test it out now and ill get back to you!!... thanks again

Comment: @user3355603 did you try it?

Comment: Yep all good tweaked your answer a bit but got there in the end!! cant accept coz i have got a good enough rep!! but thank you very much!!